# On the proof about the dimension of the conformal group of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections, geometric-transformation

I have been reading the book "Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry" by S. Kobayashi. More concretely, I am trying to understand the proof of the Theorem 6.1 of Chapter IV.

**Theorem 6.1 (S. Kobayashi, 1954)**: Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$, and $P$ a conformal structure on $M$. Then, the conformal transformation group  Conf$(M)$ of $M$ is a Lie group with dimension $\leq \frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)$.

I think I understood the essence of the proof, which is the following: a conformal structure $P$ on $M$ is determinated by a (unique) Cartan connection on $P$ that "comes from" the restriction of the canonical form of second frame bundle $P^2(M)$ to $P$ (that connection is constructed in the section 5 of the same chapter and extended to a Cartan connection on $P$ thanks to Theorem 4.2).
The uniqueness of that Cartan connection holds since $n\geq 3$. 
Now, by using the Theorem 3.1 (of the same book), that states that the group $U(P,\omega)$ of automorphisms of $P$ that preserve the Cartan connection $\omega$, is a Lie group and has dimension $\leq \dim P = \frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)$, we obtain the result.

Unfortunately, there are two details that I cannot understand. That is why I am posting this question.

(1) In the page 143, it is written "Assume that $n\geq 3$, so that the **normal Cartan connection is unique**. Then, for each automorphism $f$ of $P$, $f_*$ (restricted to $P$), preserves the normal connection."

I suppose that this means that for any conformal transformation $f$ on $M$, the induced map $f_*: P^2(M) \rightarrow P^2(M)$ that sends $P$ into $P$ preserves the Cartan connection $\omega$ on $P$. Thus, we have that any conformal transformation is an automorphism of $U(P,\omega)$ and then Conf$(M) \subset U(P, \omega)$. However this affirmation is not clear for me. In other words, **how do we know that if the Cartan connection is unique, then any automorphism of $P$ preserves that connection?**

(2) The other detail that intrigues me is the following: **Do we have the equality Conf$(M) = U(P, \omega)$ in general or just Conf$(M) \subset U(P, \omega)$?**
By reading the book it seems that the equality holds; that should justify the fact that Conf$(M)$ is a Lie group by using Theorem 3.1, but I still can't see how to prove this fact.

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the book at hand, and I am not sure wheher the interpretation of the construction you give is really correct. (I would think that only obtains a Cartan connection on the subbundle $P$ and not on the full second order frame bundle, but actually this is not really relevant for the answer.) Also, I assume that the meaning of "automorphism $f$ of $P$" includes that $f$ preserves the soldering form, so it is indeed induced by a conformal isometry of $M$.

Then the answer to (1) basically is that given the map $\tilde f:P\to P$ induced by $f$ and $\omega$, the pullback $\tilde f^*\omega$ also is a Cartan connection on $P$, which has all the properties of $\omega$ that are required for the uniquness statement. (This partially follows from the construction of $\tilde f$ and partly from the fact that the curvature of $\tilde f^*\omega$ is the pullback of the cuvature of $\omega$.) Then indeed uniqueness implies that $f^*\omega=\omega$.

For (2) you actually do have equality. Suppose that $F:P\to P$ is a principal bundle map such that $F^*\omega=\omega$. Then one deduces that $F$ is the restriction to $P$ of the prolongation of its base map $f:M\to M$. Since this prolongation preserves $P$, it follows that $f$ is a conformal ismoetry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay!
The first answer is super clear for me. I see now how can we use the uniqueness of the Cartan form. 
However, for the second part I don't follow the argument. Why can we say that if $F: P \rightarrow P$ is a principal bundle map such that $F^*\omega = \omega$, then it is equal to the restriction of the prolongation of $f$? 
By prolongation of $f$ I suppose that you mean the associated map $\widetilde{f}:P^2(M) \rightarrow P^2(M)$

Comment: This is a bit tricky, since it depends of constructions. But in any case, the $\omega$ is related to the soldering form. So if $F$ preserves $\omega$, the induced map on the frame bundle preserves the soldering form. Thus it is the prolongation of its base map. Similarly you get this for the second jet part.

Comment: Okay, I still don't see it but I will think about it carefully. Anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: First of all, my apologies for going back to the question after 3 months. All this time I have been studying all the details of the proof and this last detail of the surjectivity is still there. By "solder form" I suppose that you mean what S. Kobayashi called in his book "canonical form" (pg. 140) From your answer I guess that the following is true: if a bundle map $F: P \rightarrow P$ preserves the Cartan connection (related to the solder form), then it is the restriction of the prolongation of its base map.

Comment: And we can use that to prove both the injectivity and surjectivity of the map $\text{Conf}(M) \rightarrow \text{Aut}(P, \omega)$, $f \mapsto f^*$.
My question is, why is this true? Would you give me a reference where I can see the result or a comment explaining why this works? Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for taking your time. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SpTgQPjRW6g75d3Qn9dqscuMAyl04emx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thers is no real need to go to $P^2M$ here. One of the properties of the Cartan connection is that it descends to the canonical form on $P^1M$ (whose restriction to the conformal frame bundle I meant by "soldering form"). And a principal bundle map on $P^1$ that preserves this canonical form is the prolongation of its base map. One can probably also argue like that on the level of $P^2M$, but this is a point of view that I am not closely familiar with.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the second comment: We seem to agree that an auromorphism of $(P,\omega)$ is uniquely determined by it's base map and that this base map is a conformal isometry. Since conversely, any conformal isometry lifts to an automorphism (with the given map as its base map), we are done. (We have proved bijectivity of $Aut(P)\to Conf(M)$ rather than $Conf(M)\to Aut(P)$.)

Comment: Now I clearly see the reasoning. I found that the fact for the "canonical form" is also true in the $P^2(M)$ level in S.Kobayashi, T. Nagano, "On Projective Connections" [Proposition 5]. I haven't read the proof carefully yet, but it should be something similar to that for the case of the frame bunble $P^1(M)$. Thus, we have indeed that for any bundle map $F: P^2(M) \rightarrow P^2(M)$ preserving the canonical form (preserving the Cartan connection is a sufficient condition) then the map is the prolongation of its base map and we have what we wanted.

Comment: And for the second comment. At first I tried to prove the isomorphism from $\text{Conf}(M)$ to $\text{Aut}(P,ω)$. As you pointed out in the answer, I used the uniqueness of the Cartan connection to prove that the map is well-defined and I tried to prove that it is a bijection. Now I see that the opposite direction also works and that might be easier (I thought about this and I think it's basically the same). The injectiveness must be trivial and the surjectiveness should be proved by using the fact above.

Comment: The only detail that I still don't get is: is the fact above also true for an automorphism of the subbundle $P \subset P^2(M)$? That is, if $F: P \rightarrow P$ preserves the canonical form of $P^2(M)$ (resctricted to $P$), then should it be the prolongation of its base map? We might extend the map to all $P^2(M)$ and then proceed, but I don't know how to do this. Thank you very much again for your answers.

Comment: The extension of $F$ to $P^2M$ is uniquely determineb by equivariancy (i.e. by the fact that the extension should be a homomorphism of principal bundles). Since the canonical form is equivariant, it follows that the extension preserves the canonical form.

Comment: Interesting! So you define the extension by using the right actions (in order to make it a bundle morphism) and using precisely this equivariance, two extensions that coincide in $P$ must coincide in the entire $P^2(M)$ too (so there is only one). I didn't know about this beautiful fact! Is this true in general? i.e, if we have a principal $G$-bundle $P$ and a principal $H$-subbundle $Q$, can we always extend an automorphism of $Q$ to one of $P$? I guess we can. About the details, I completely understood the proof now. Thanks again for your explanations and your time.